# Gradle to use internal JFrog Aritifactory to get spring boot library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I was to force `Gradle 7.4.2` to use internal JFrog Artifactory to download the build dependency files.

But when I build it was trying to download it from `https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory` location. I want gradle to use our internal JFrog Artifcatory to downbload for `spring-boot` jar files.

Any help to force to use only internal repo to download the dependency files?

Here is build script `build.gradle` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://artifactory-local/artifactory/dss-core-maven-virtual/'
            credentials {
                username "${artifactory_user}"
                password "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        // https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
    id 'idea'
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

 
repositories {  
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "${artifactory_user}"
            password "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        url = 'https://artifactory-local/artifactory/dss-core-maven-virtual/'
    } 
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.212'
 
    testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

**Error message during run time:**

```
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden: https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.7.1/spring-boot-starter-data-j
pa-2.7.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden: https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.7.1/spring-boot-starter-actuat
or-2.7.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden: https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/com/h2database/h2/2.1.212/h2-2.1.212.pom)]
Failed to get resource: HEAD. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden: https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.7.1/spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.pom)]
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|E4|Unconstrained build operations Thread 36|2022-07-14 16:13:14.700 CDT|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1714)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1513)
```

Answer (score 0):

found answer here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4310

```
settings.gradle must be used from v.4.4

// settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "My Custom Plugin Repository"
            url = "https://..."
        }
    }
}
```